# Get Item position of MvxListView by cliking on item

Tags: listview, xamarin.android

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource productlist"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/productitem" />
```

how to get Item position by clicking on row of this **MvxListView** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int cposition =0; // your global variable 

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
           cposition =position;
    }  
 });
```

Comment: I am not using Adapter,I am using ItemTemplate to bind the data

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the way *MvxListView* works it swallows the item position in handling the item click event and dispatching to your command. See [bind click event](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/f72a92e8a81b9179d1f75d6214eee8c9ca176221/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxListView.cs#L92) and [dispatch command](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/f72a92e8a81b9179d1f75d6214eee8c9ca176221/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxListView.cs#L112).

You can subclass *MvxListView* and override the *ExecuteCommandOnItem()* method to capture the position.

Something like:

```c#
public class MyMvxListView : MvxListView
{
    // add constructors here

    // property to capture position
    public int Position { get; private set; }

    public override void ExecuteCommandOnItem(ICommand command, int position)
    {
        // store position
        Position = position;

        // call base class
        base.ExecuteCommandOnItem(command, position);   
    }
}
```